# spring kafka retry on custom exception logic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using the spring kafka in my project and working on adding the retry functionality.
As part of code workflow, a message is consumed and we make a rest call to some endpoint. If it fails I need to retry. Below code is working fine in terms of container factory and doing retry for some exceptions.

```
@Bean
public <V> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, V> jsonSerdeKafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaOperations<String, V> jsonSerdeKafkaTemplate) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, V> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(buildJsonSerdeConsumerProperties()));
    DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler =  new DefaultErrorHandler(new LoggingDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(jsonSerdeKafkaTemplate));
    defaultErrorHandler.addRetryableExceptions(<SomeHttpExceptionClass>);
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(defaultErrorHandler);
    return factory;
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is there some option in spring kafka to do retry for some custom logic within the exception? Example I need to retry when the rest api call fails with http status code as 503,429, etc and not on 504.
2. default max poll records is 500. With stateful retry using DefaultErrorHandler every failed record is sent to broker to ensure no rebalancing occurs. So let's say 500 records are polled and spring gave first record to kafka to process. If it fails, then all 500 records are discarded and polled again from the broker starting from the failed offset?

**Scenario**

Data is produced to topic has 2 partitions and is consumed by a single consumer. For error scenario, fixed backoff with interval 30 secs is applied.

1. Data is present in partition-0 at 12:00:00 am and consumer consumed record and failed during processing. With fixed backOff, next processing is done at 12:00:30 am.
2. Data produced in partition-1 at 12:00:30 am. Data is consumed and failed during processing. Fixed backoff is also applied with 30 secs.

Consumer retried partition-0 record again at 12:00:30am and then record from partition-1.

Does kafka makes sure that every record is retried after 30secs when a single consumer is listening to both partitions? I have seen cases where a record from partition-0 is retried after 30 secs for some time and then next retry started happening with 1 mins interval.

Please see below the code implemented and the screenshot of logs which says backOff started with 1 min interval from 30 secs interval.

[image]

```
 private <K, V> DefaultErrorHandler initDefaultErrorHandlerWithCustomBackOff(KafkaOperations<K, V> kafkaTemplate) {
        DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(new LoggingDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate));
        defaultErrorHandler.setBackOffFunction((consumerRecord, e) -> {
            if (isRetryableHttpStatusCode(httpCode(e))) {
                return new FixedBackOff(30000, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS); --> Error Scenario 
            }
            return new FixedBackOff(0,0);
        });
        return defaultErrorHandler;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see

```java
/**
 * Set a function to dynamically determine the {@link BackOff} to use, based on the
 * consumer record and/or exception. If null is returned, the default BackOff will be
 * used.
 * @param backOffFunction the function.
 * @since 2.6
 */
public void setBackOffFunction(BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, BackOff> backOffFunction) {
```

Return a `FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)` for not-retryable conditions.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

> You can provide the error handler with a `BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, BackOff>` to determine the `BackOff` to use, based on the failed record and/or the exception:

```
handler.setBackOffFunction((record, ex) -> { ... });
```

> If the function returns null, the handler’s default `BackOff` will be used.

> Set `resetStateOnExceptionChange` to true and the retry sequence will be restarted (including the selection of a new BackOff, if so configured) if the exception type changes between failures. When `false`, the exception type is not considered.

Starting with version 2.9, this is now `true` by default.

You will need to traverse the cause chain to reach the root cause exception.

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. "I get an NPE" is not enough information; include a full stack trace.

Comment: Apologies for adding code in comments Gary. Please ignore my previous comment. Seems like code is working now. thanks for the information

Comment: @GaryRussell, How does it work for reactive types? How will you get the `record` ? because reactive types will give only the error. You want me to create separate question in SO? I can do.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. The container is not reactive.

Comment: @GaryRussell, i have seen a scenario where a record is being retried with fixedBackOff of 30 secs and after some time retries started happening with 1 min.
I have updated the original question under Scenario heading. Please help advise if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Don't ask new, unrelated, questions in comments; it doesn't help people find answers. No, there is no guarantee that the records will be received in the same order after a back off. Sometimes partition 1 will be received before partition 0. You can increase the concurrency to match the number of partitions so there is a consumer per partition, or set the new (2.9+) property `seeksAfterError` to false and Spring won't re-fetch the records but present them in the same order each time.